# how to stop the else condition from executing?

Tags: jquery

I have a condition where the else condition executes even the the if condition is true. How manually stop the else condition from executing when the true condition executes?
I tried return false. In this case, break does not work.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) 
{
    if (e.which == 38)
    {
        code inside works
    } 
   else if (e.which == 40) 
    {
        if (current_list_item >= end_of_list) 
        {
            alert("Reached the end");
            return false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("Add more items");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your IF condition isn't "true". Check your variables using `alert([current_list_item, end_of_list]);`

Comment: Which `if/else` pair seems to be behaving unexpectedly? Nothing looks immediately wrong to me. Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is a very useful tool for this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to - aside from using some non-standard browser with an absolutely atrocious Javascript engine, it's simply not possible for both the if and else conditions of the statement to execute. Something else is happening - likely multiple events being fired at (almost) the same time - and you'll need to find out what that is.

Comment: if its not true why the alert("reached the end") gets executed? I checked variable of current_list_item and its says 25 and the end_of_list is at 25

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible. The "if" condition is true.

Comment: Remove the word "probably" from this answer and replace "is" with "isn't"  :)